# Oracle stored procedure, SELECT

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create procedure, that displays events beetween two dates and my code doesen't compile. In cmd prompt SELECT formula works, but here doesen't want to. Im new to Oracle database, here's the code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SHOW_EVENTS 
(
  SINCE IN DATE 
, TTO IN DATE 
) AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM events
   WHERE EVENT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(SINCE,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(TTO,'dd/mm/yyyy')

END SHOW_EVENTS;
```

Comment: PL/SQL isn't setup to run SQL and give you a resultset. It's designed to do SOMETHING with the SQL resultset -  you need to SELECT your results INTO a pl/sql table for processing. If you just want to run the query, do it in straight SQL. there are many questions here on SO that address this

Comment: also, SINCE and TTO are both DATEs. You don't need to TO_DATE a DATE. Just in your SQL say EVENT_DATE BETWEEN SINCE and TTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues.  First, the query should be:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
WHERE e.EVENT_DATE BETWEEN SINCE AND TTO;
```

There is zero reason to convert a date to a date.  The only possible reason would be if you wanted to truncate the date to the nearest day (because Oracle dates have time components).  That is better done as:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
WHERE e.EVENT_DATE BETWEEN trunc(SINCE) AND trunc(TTO);
```

More importantly, you cannot (easily) do what you want.  Not with a stored procedure, because these do not return result sets.  Not with a view, because these are not parameterized.  Not easily with a function -- writing functions that return a "table" is rather complex in Oracle.  It is not for the uninitiated.

Comment: it's not that it's 'complex' i think it's that you should just use SQL when you need SQL